# Find the smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ has an element of given order.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Hint given is to split $|g|$ in cycles of prime lengths.

Say, $n=1000.$

So, factored $1000$ as $2*2*2*5*5*5$ in order to find minimum value of LCM.
In fact, there is no other prime factorization possible.

Say, a set of disjoint cycles given by $$(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7, 8, 9 ,10, 11)(12,13, 14 ,15, 16)(17, 18, 19, 20, 21)$$. But,  $21$ is not correct!

Have taken a wrong approach then.

Also, why need prime length cycles in group $S_n$ to generate smallest sum as $=n.$

Not clear if this is some property of prime factorization, i.e. to generate smallest sum.

Say, if had split $1000$ into $2.4.25.5$, then would have got sum of cycle lengths as:$2+4+25+5=36.$

But, then is there a proof of this property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint as written is somewhat misleading: Notice that all of the cycles in your permutation in $S_{21}$ have order $2$ or $5$, so the element has order $\operatorname{lcm}(2, 5) = 10$.

Since $1\,000=2^3 5^3$, we can see that to avoid this problem we'll need to find nonoverlapping cycles of lengths $2^3$ and $5^3$.

Comment: But, the answer for $n$ is not $21$?

Comment: @jiten Why not take a moment to think? The answer is clearly stated as $2^3 + 5^3$.

Comment: @jiten Notice that your permutation in $S_{21}$ has the same order as $(1,2)(7,8,9,10,11)$: If your permutation contains a $k$-cycle, adding more nonoverlapping $k$-cycles does not change the order. So, a minimal permutation of a given order is always a product of cycles of distinct lengths.

Comment: Also, some hints on why prime factorization yields the smallest sum of factors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$\lvert g\rvert =\rm {lcm}(|c_1\rvert, \lvert c_2\rvert, \dots, \lvert c_k\rvert) $, where $g=c_1c_2\dots c_k$ is the cycle decomposition of $g$.

Write $$m=\prod_ip_i^{a_i}$$, for the prime factorization of $m$.  For the purposes of this problem you can assume that $\lvert c_i\rvert =p_i^{a_i}$, (since this will give the shortest permutation with the required order).

Then we get $$n=\sum_ip_i^{a_i}$$.

---

To do a different example,  let $m=575$.  Then $m=5^2\cdot 23$.  Then $n=5^2+23=48$, so $S_{48}$ is the smallest symmetric group such that it has an element of order $575$.

Comment: Request to quick ome more interesting cases. That link up with other areas, if possible; say if can find link with counting using group actions. Actually, am learning; and am not clear if such example is possible or not! So, sorry in advance; if wrong.