# $S_n$ relation between vertices in cycle and group order.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

This is more of an afterthought to my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4484732/424260).

The interaction among the vertices (shown in disjoint cycles of $S_n$) are derived from the underlying operations (like: reflection, rotation) to yield group elements being more than vertices in cycles.

Say, $S_3$ has three vertices in cycles, but has $6$ as order.

But, the number of such actions (as in $S_3$ too) is shown by different set of cycles.
Say $(1)$ for identity, $(123)$ for $R_1$, and so on.

As answer to [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4484732/424260) is $a.b= 1000$ , then only $a+b$ vertices are there, and generate $1000$ maximum group actions (or their combinations). These $1000$ are the group elements.
While vertices are just a set on which actions apply.

If so, what is the exact relationship between the set of vertices and group elements?

In $S_{133}$ with $a=8, b=125$, how $a+b= 133$ vertices can possibly generate $1000$ group elements  is unclear (have only two operations known over symmetric group: reflection, rotation).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "vertices" here?

Comment: @Shaun Vertices are those in cycles of symmetric group. Seems am wrong as symmetric group don't always correspond to a geometric object; as has $n!$ permutations, unlike $2n$ for dihedral objects. Still what would be elements in cycles? And how is their relation to group order is defined for $S_133$, with a particular constraint on element order.

Comment: Do you mean the $a_i$ in, say, $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$?

Comment: @Shaun yes, but seems the vertices should be worded differently; as not a dihedral group with $2n$ actions on $n$ vertices. //Please see my last comment, after edit.

Comment: The symmetric group has all the permutations, not just "reflections" and "rotations". You're trying to impose a geometric structure on the "vertices" which just isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of elements of $S_n$ is

$$n!=n\times (n-1)\times\dots\times 2\times 1.$$

Remember that $n$ is the number of elements of the set $S_n$ acts on by definition, which is typically $\{1, \dots, n\}$.